# no ttyS* in CentOS6

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, serial-port, centos6

I'm working on a device which connect through serial connection, ans the OS is CentOS 6.

My kernel is a container based on a root kernel comes from Promox. 
So, I installed all driver of the device and everything seems flawless.

However, it seems like my kernel don't avactivate the serial connecion. I can't find ttyS* files at all.

Does anyone have this situation already ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Is there anything in kernel log on the host side? Something with 'serial' or 'tty' in it? It's strange that /dev/ttyS0 doesn't even show.

Comment: @bytefire Why so?  *ttySx* is reserved for 8250 serial driver. Otherwise it might be something different. Since OP didn't give the details (poorly written question), we don't know if it's by design (hardware specific) or not.

Comment: @0andriy Usually Linux creates 4 serial ports: ttyS0-3. By usually I mean x86 systems. See http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.10/source/arch/x86/include/asm/serial.h#L22.

Comment: @bytefire, I know. The letter **S** is dedicated for exact driver, i.e. 8250. If you have no such hardware you will have no such devices, though it might be still a bug (inconvenience) that there are 4 ports reserved for legacy ISA compatibility.

Comment: @0andriy "though it might be still a bug (inconvenience) that there are 4 ports reserved for legacy ISA compatibility" - yes. And that's what I meant that it is strange that there won't be any ttyS0 : )